# File reading and writing in cp866 encoding in C++

Tags: c++, file, winapi, encoding, dos

How do i correctly read and write file with text in cp866 encoding in C++?

UPD: i found a way to write to a file

```
wofstream rstrm(fileName);
rstrm.imbue(locale("rus_rus.866"));
rstrm << text_in_cyrillic.c_str();
rstrm.close();
```

Now how can i read file in similar way? I need to read file content to tstring object.

Comment: Why do you need to? How about using UTF-8? And `std::string s; file >> s;` will work, but it's probably not what you want.

Comment: @ybungalobill unfortunately, it's not my case.

Answer (score 0):

Use `WideCharToMultiByte` and tell it cp866, and write the results.